# React Native screen rendering issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i am new in react native. Here is the environment i use:

```
> Environment:   OS:  macOS Sierra 10.12.6   Node:  6.11.3   Yarn: 
> 1.1.0   npm:  5.3.0   Watchman:  4.9.0   Xcode:  Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235   Android Studio:  2.3 AI-162.4069837
> 
> Packages: (wanted => installed)   react: 16.0.0-beta.5 =>
> 16.0.0-beta.5   react-native: 0.49.1 => 0.49.1
```

I have problem in the ios (using iphone 5s with ios 11) applications that is the screen is not rendered properly. This problem is intermittent, and it is happen when moving from one menu to another menu. I am using react-navigation (Using TabNavigator and StackNavigator). This problem is never happen in android emulator. Thank you.

[image: Screen problem]

Comment: Did you try to reset the simulator ? Or use an other one, or an other version of the simulator ?

Comment: For reset emulator i have tried it, for using other version i haven't tried it